# Visual Studio adds :1 to title

Tags: visual-studio

Today I updated to Visual Studio 2019 16.7.6 now I saw, that on the tab riders of code files there is the name and a ":1" added to it, like "Skaarhoj.vb:1". Does anybody know what that is?

Answer (score 3):

- It's visible when you have multiple views/windows (tabs) open for the same file.

  - Note that this is not the same thing as the split-view you can activate by dragging the handle at the top of the vertical scrollbar.
  - This is not a new feature - I can remember using it in VS2013, possibly VS2010.
- The first window/tab has `:1`, the second has `:2` and so on.
- You can open new windows for most (but not all) files and file-types via `(VS Main Menu) > Window > New Window`
- Note that not all editors/file-types support having multiple windows open simultaneously, so that menu item may appear disabled for some files.

[image]

Comment: Aha, I never stumbled upon this. Thanks for claifying.